# Dynamic vs static array in c

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic, static

The following code creates an array with the malloc function. But i know that this can be done much simplier with just int array[size]. I think this is static array. But with the malloc function is it dynamic array? I found this code in the net... What is really happening and whats the difference between a static array and a dynamic array(and static memory between heap memory). Can you change the size of the dynamic array during runtime? or... what i dont know exactly... If someone could explain i would appreciate :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int size;
    int i;
    printf("Choose size of array: ");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    /*---MALLOC/FREE---*/
    int *m_array = (int *)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(int));
    memset(m_array,'\0',size+1);

    for(i=0; i<size ; i++)
    { 
        m_array[i]=i;
        printf("%d ",m_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(m_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int *m_array` is a `Pointer` not an `Array`.

Comment: `int array[size]` is a [variable length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Also, you may be interested in the `realloc` function.

Comment: `The following code creates an array with the malloc function` No is not. With `malloc` you request an Amount of memory from your `OS` and if you get it you set your `pointer` to points there.

Comment: @Michi the C Standard says that `malloc` creates an array

Comment: @Michi i ment using the malloc...

Comment: @M.M no, the C standard does not say that `malloc` creates an array

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There are several flavors of arrays, depending on how and where they are declared.

**Fixed-length Arrays**

Fixed-length arrays must have their size determined at *compile time*.  You cannot change the size of a fixed-length array after it has been defined.

Fixed-length arrays are declared in one of the following ways:

```
T a[N];
T a[N] = { /* initializer list */ };
char_type a[N] = "string literal";
T a[]  = { /* initializer list */ };
char_type a[]  = "string literal";
```

In the first three cases, `N` must be a *constant expression* whose value must be known at compile time.  In the first three cases, the size of the array is taken from `N`; in the last two cases, it's taken from the number of elements in the initializer list or the size of the string literal.

The initial contents of a fixed-length array depend on its *storage duration* and whether an initializer has been supplied.

If the array has `static` storage duration (meaning it was declared at file scope outside of any function body, or was declared with the `static` keyword) and no initializer is present, then all of the array elements are initialized to `0` (for scalars) or `NULL` (for pointers).  If `T` is an aggregate type such as a `struct` or an array type, then each member of the aggregate is initialized with a `0` or `NULL`.  `union` types are similarly zeroed out.

If the array has `auto` storage duration (meaning it was declared within a function or block without the `static` keyword) and no initializer is present, then the contents of the array are *indeterminate* - basically, garbage.

If the array is declared with an initializer list (regardless of storage duration), then the initial values of the array elements correspond to the initializer.  If there are fewer elements in the initializer than the array (for example, `N` is 10 but you only initialize the first 5 elements), then the remaining elements are initialized *as though* the array had `static` storage duration.  IOW, given the declaration

```
int a[10] = {0, 1, 2};
```

then the initial contents of the array are `{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Fixed-length arrays containing string values may be initialized using a string literal.  C allows for "wide" character strings, so `char_type` may be either `char` or `wchar_t`.  The rules are the same for regular initializer lists, except that `N` (if specified) must be at least 1 more than the length of the string to account for the string terminator.

This means that

```
char a[10] = "test";
```

will be initialized as `{'t', 'e', 's', 't', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}` and

```
char a[] = "test";
```

will be initialized as `{'t', 'e', 's', 't', 0}`.

Arrays with `static` storage duration are stored such that they are available as soon as the program is loaded, and aren't released until the program exits.  This usually means that they're stored in a memory segment like `.data` or `.bss` (or the equivalent for whatever executable format your system uses).

Arrays with `auto` storage duration are stored such that they are allocated at block or function entry and released at block or function exit (in practice, they'll probably be allocated at function entry, regardless of whether they're limited to a smaller scope within the function) - this typically translates to the stack, although it doesn't *have* to.

**Variable-length Arrays**

Variable-length arrays were added in C99 - they behave *mostly* like fixed-length arrays, except that their size is established at *run time*; `N` does not have to be a compile-time constant expression:

```
int n;
printf( "gimme the array size: ");
scanf( "%d", &n );
T a[n]; // for any type T
```

Contrary to what their name implies, you cannot change the size of a variable-length array after it has been defined.  "Variable-length" simply means that the size isn't fixed at compile time, and can change from definition to definition.

Since their size isn't set until runtime, variable-length arrays may not be declared at file scope or with the `static` keyword, nor can they be declared with an initializer list.  Exactly how the space for VLAs is managed is up to the implementation; it may be (and usually is) taken from the stack, but AFAIK may be taken from somewhere else.

**Dynamic Arrays**

Dynamic arrays are not really "arrays" as such, at least in terms of the data types of the objects we use to manage them.  Dynamic arrays are allocated at runtime using one of `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, and that storage is held until released with a call to `free`.

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N ); // where N may be either a compile-time or
                                // run-time expression
...
free( p );
```

A dynamic array may be resized using the `realloc` library function, like so:

```
/**
 * If realloc fails, it will return NULL and leave the original array in 
 * place.  We assign the result to a temporary variable so we don't risk
 * losing our only reference to that memory. 
 */
T *tmp = realloc( p, sizeof *p * new_size );  
if ( tmp )                                    
  p = tmp;
```

While the memory for the array elements themselves is taken from the heap (or whatever dynamic memory pool), the memory for the *pointer variable* `p` will be allocated from either a `.bss` or `.data` segment or from the stack, based on `p`'s storage duration (`static` or `auto`).

Memory allocated with `malloc` or `realloc` is not initialized; the contents of that memory will be indeterminate.  Memory allocated with `calloc` will be initialized with zeros.

**Arrays vs. Pointers**

At some point, somebody is going to tell you that "an array is just a pointer".  That person is not correct.

When you declare an array (either fixed- or variable-length), enough storage is set aside for the elements of that array and *nothing else*; no storage is set aside for any metadata such as the array length or a pointer to the first element.  Given the declaration

```
T a[N];
```

then the storage will look something like this:

```
    +---+
 a: |   | a[0]
    +---+
    |   | a[1]
    +---+
    |   | a[2]
    +---+
     ...
    +---+ 
    |   | a[N-1]
    +---+
```

There is no object `a` apart from the array elements themselves (or, more properly, the object `a` *is* the elements of the array), and the expression `a` may not be the target of an assignment.

But...

The expression `a[i]` is *defined* as `*(a + i)`; that is, given a pointer value `a`, offset `i` *elements* (*not bytes!*) from that address and dereference the result.  But if `a` is not a pointer, how can that work?

Like this - except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used as an array initializer in a declaration, an *expression* of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be *converted* ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

This has several implications:

- The expressions `a`, `&a`, and `&a[0]` will all yield the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array), but the *types* of the expressions will be different (`T *`, `T (*)[N]`, and `T *`, respectively);

  The subscript operator `[]` works equally well with both array expressions and pointer expressions (indeed, it's *defined* to work on pointer expressions);

  When you pass an array expression to a function, what you are *actually* passing is a pointer value, not the entire array;

For dynamic arrays, the situation is different.  Given the line

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

then your storage will look something like this:

```
   +---+
p: |   | ---+
   +---+    |
    ...     |
     +------+
     |
     V
   +---+
   |   | p[0]
   +---+
   |   | p[1]
   +---+
    ...   
   +---+
   |   | p[N-1]
   +---+
```

In this case, `p` *is* a separate object from the array.  Thus, `&p` *won't* give you the same value as `p` and `&p[0]`, and its type will be `T **` as opposed to `T (*)[N]`.  Also, since `p` is just a pointer variable, you can assign a new value to it (although if you do so without `free`ing the memory it points to first, you'll create a memory leak).

Similarly, `sizeof p` *won't* behave like `sizeof a`; it will simply return the size of the pointer variable, not the size of the allocated memory that the pointer points *to*.

Comment: Amazing answer! But one nitpick about the statement *"except that N (if specified) must be at least 1 more than the length of the string to account for the string terminator"*. That's not technically correct. If N is specified, it must be greater than **or equal** to the length of the string. If N is equal to the length of the string, the result is an array of characters without a NUL terminator. For example, `a[4] = "test";` is allowed by the C specification, see paragraph 6.7.9/14

Answer (score 2):

Static arrays are allocated memory at compile time and the memory is allocated on the stack. Whereas, the dynamic arrays are allocated memory at the runtime and the memory is allocated from heap.

This is static integer array i.e. fixed memory assigned before runtime

```
int arr[] = { 1, 3, 4 };
```

This is dynamic integer array i.e memory assigned on runtime

```
int* arr = new int[3];
```

Comment: Int *arr is not an Array, it's a Pointer

Comment: I know. Dynamic memory is allocated in pointer form. It has name of arr, it is not an array

Comment: The memory doesn't got allocated in Pointer. The pointer points there.

Comment: I am saying the same thing mate. Dynamic memory is allocated in pointer form and pointer points on that location where the data is, either it is in distributed or sequential form.

Comment: static arrays do not use the stack... that is automatic arrays.

Comment: @Muhammad Noman: `new` is from C++ but question is for C.

Answer (score 1):

You're using dynamic arrays of size+1 and adding elements to it (from 0 to size) and releasing the space at the end before returning 0. So when in your case, int *m_array is a pointer to an int. What you're doing on line 13 is declaration:

```
(int *m_array) =...
```

and allocation:

```
...(int *)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(int));
```

Since it is a dynamic array, you are allocating on heap and is kept until it is freed (that's why you have free(m_array) at the end). If it was static, you could've initialized the array this way:

```
int m_array[size];
```

And it would've been allocated on static storage area (unless is automatic) and would be deallocated as soon as the program ended. You can't change the size of an static array in C, so you need to use a dynamic array. You use [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) when you want to change to size of a dynamic array.